# How to parallel api calls and keep the order of the responses in a list for the ui to present (RxJS Observables)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Challenge!

My issue is as follow:

I have a function that gets Observable and needs to enrich the person data and update an observer with an Observable

Which Person object looks like:

```
export interface Person {
  personId: string;
  children: Child[];
}

export interface Child {
  childId: string;
}
```

and the EnrichPerson looks like:

```
export interface EnrichedPerson {
  personName: string;
  parsonCountry: string;
  children: EnrichedChild[]
}

export interface EnrichedChild {
  childName: string;
  childAge: number
}
```

So, what I did is this:

```
private myFunc(listOfPeople: Observable<Person[]>): void {

  // initializing listOfEnrichedPeople , this will be the final object that will be updated to the behaviour subject 
  // "public currentListOfPeople = new BehaviorSubject<EnrichedPerson[]>([]);"

  let listOfEnrichedPeople: EnrichedPerson[] = [];

  listOfPeople.subscribe((people: Person[]) => {
      people.map((person: Person, personIdx: number) => {
          // here im setting up a new list of enriched children list cause each person have a list like this
          // and for each of the children I need to perform also an api call to get its info - youll see soon
          let listOfEnrichedChildren: EnrichedChild[] = [];
          // here im taking a list of the ids of the people, cause im gonna perform an api call that will give me their names
          let ids: string[] = people.map((person: Person) => person.personId);

          this._peopleDBApi.getPeopleNames(ids).subscribe((names: string[]) => { 
            // here I though if I already have the name I can set it up
              listOfEnrichedPeople.push({
              personName: names[personIdx],
              parsonCountry: "",
              childrenNames: [] });

              // now for each person, i want to take its list of children and enrich their data
              person.childrenIds.map((child: Child) => {
                // the catch is here, the getChildInfo api only perform it per id and cant recieve a list, and I need to keep the order...so did this in the
                  this._childrenDBApi.getChildInfo(child.childId).subscribe((childInfo: ChildInfo) => {
                                listOfEnrichedChildren.push({
                                childName: childInfo.name,
                                childAge: childInfo.age});
                    });
                });
              listOfEnrichedPeople[personIdx].parsonCountry = person.country;
              listOfEnrichedPeople[personIdx].children = listOfEnrichedChildren;
            });
        });
      this.currentListOfPeople.next(listOfEnrichedPeople);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        self.listOfEnrichedPeople.next([]);
      });
}
```

my problem is when I make the children api call, cause I if the first id takes 2 sec to respond and the one after it only 1 sec so im losing my order...i need to keep the order that I originally got in the function parameter...how can I make it parallel for better performance and also keep my orders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index argument of the `.map()` callback and assign to the list via that index instead of using `.push()`. That way, regardless of timing, the api response will get assigned to the correct position in the list.

```
person.childrenIds.map(({child: Child}, index) => {
  this._childrenDBApi.getChildInfo(child.childId).subscribe((childInfo: ChildInfo) => {
    listOfEnrichedChildren[index] = {
      childName: childInfo.name,
      childAge: childInfo.age};
    };
    // ...
```

Comment: thats nice...but is that also happening in parallel..? also, in this case, i always get another empty object from some reason...:/ im trying to figure this out

Comment: Yes, still in parallel. I'm only suggesting a change to the content of the call back, nothing else that would affect use of the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new `Observable` containing the results of getting each child/person from the API (in parallel) *and* the original index in the array.

You can then flatten all of those results down into a single new array, sort them by the original index and return them

```
const getEnrichedChildren = (children: Person[]): Observable<EnrichedPerson[]> => 
  //create an observable from the array of children
  Observable.of(...children)
    //map to a new observable containing both the result from the API and the 
    //original index.  use flatMap to merge the API responses
    .flatMap((child, index) => peopleApi.getPerson(child.personId).map(enriched => ({ child: enriched, index })))
    //combine all results from that observable into a single observable containing 
    //an array of EnrichedPerson AND original index
    .toArray()
    //map the result to a sorted list of EnrichedPerson
    .map(unorderedChildren => unorderedChildren.sort(c => c.index).map(c => c.child));
```

The readability of this is pretty terrible here but I've kept everything in one block so you can see how things chain together